# after update android studio error not show and suggestion not appear in xml file

Tags: java, android

Before update android studio always show the error like if In linear layout declare the orientation. If write anything then show the error but after update android studio I have to write `orientation="ygsdjgas"` isn't show the error. Please look in the image

I want to show error like before update. Before updated android studio I have declare `orientation="ahsgdah"` then show the error but after update it not show the error and also no any suggestion like "horizontal and vertical"

[image]

Comment: try invalidate cache and restart

Comment: Sir I have already try this but not resolve that.

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm below highlighted options in android studio
[image]

If still doesn't work then first take backup of your project then delete .idea folder and all .iml files from the project, restarting Android Studio and rebuilding gradle did the trick. Intellisense (Autocomplete suggestion) in XML support library will work.

Checking out files from Version Control or copying all the source files in a new project would do the trick as well.

Comment: Sir I have uninstall my android studio but its not working well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved. Only I went to the C drive and deleted the .androidstudio file and re-opened the Android studio and all got right for me.this is working for me